# Matlab program to plot summation with variable upper bound

Tags: matlab, plot

How would I go about writing a matlab program to plot a summation with a variable upper bound?

For example, assuming some discrete function `x[n]`, how would I plot the summation of `x[m]` from `m = 0` to `m = n` as a function of `n`?

I tried `symsum(xn,m, 0, n)`, but received an error that indicated the upper bound must be scalar (`n` was defined as `n = 0:1:1000`)

Comment: It sounds a lot like you want to integrate the function from a to b.  Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: Yes for the most part, except it's for the analysis of a discrete signal, not a continuous one, so an integral is exactly correct.

Comment: Depending on what `x(n)` looks like you should be able to do something like `xn = @(x) x; answer = sum(xn(0:1000));`

Comment: Or are you looking for a running total?  In that case `answer = cumsum(xn(0:1000));`

Comment: I believe the first solution is closer to what I'm aiming for. The general goal of this is, with some function x[n] which is composed of an exponential multiplied with a step function, to plot the function y[n] = summation from m=-inf to m=n of x[m]

Comment: If you want to make an approximation of the integral, it's better to use the trapezoidal method `cumtrapz`. `cumsum` typically leads to a small offset from the real integral, whereas the trapezoidal method is designed to approximate the real integral, and is identical to the real integral if you can assume that the to-be-integrated function consists of straight lines between all your data points.

Comment: But since this is a discrete function, not a continuous one (edited question to reflect this), using the cumtrapz would give an incorrect value, correct?

Comment: @MattWalck  If you want a solution you need to provide more information about your function `x(n)` and your desired output.  Your comments make it sound like each iteration of `n` produces a time history.  This makes it sound like you want the sum of integrals of these time histories.  You have asked a far too general question expecting too specific an answer.